# Use of unassigned local variable 'p'

Tags: c#

I think if has something to do with my if statement

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace dotheaven
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //image path
        string img = "";

        //read image
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img);


        //get image dimension
        int width = bmp.Width;
        int height = bmp.Height;

        //3 bitmap for red green blue image
        Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(bmp);

        //red green blue image
        Color p;
        int t = 15;
        int x;
        int y;
        int a;
        int r;
        int g;
        int b;
        //if green
        int rl;
        int rh;
        int gl;
        int gh;
        int bl;
        int bh;
        for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
                //get pixel value
                p = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
            //extract ARGB value from p
            a = p.A;
            r = p.R;
            g = p.G;
            b = p.B;
            //if green
            rl = 64 - t;
            rh = 64 + t;
            gl = 108 + t;
            gh = 108 + t;
            bl = 111 - t;
            bh = 111 + t;
              // the if statement is chopped off, thats not reason of error
            if ((rl < r) && (rh > r) && (gl < g) && (gh > g) && (gl < g) )
            {
                pic.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(a, 64, 108, 111));
            }
            else
            {
                pic.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(200, 255, 255, 255));
            }
            //rbmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(a, r, 0, 0));
            //gmbp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(a, 0, g, 0));
            // bbmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(a, 0, 0, b));
        }
    }
    //load images
    // pictureBox1.Image = pic;
    //pic.Save("enter path");
}
}
```

Comment: There's a possibility that `p = bmp.GetPixel(x, y)` will never run if `x < width` is false, leaving `p` unassigned. You could change your assignment to `Color p = default(Color);`.

Answer (score 2):

You are only assigning `p` within the loop, (and overwriting its previous value, which is almost certainly wrong, but never mind, I suppose that will be the subject of your next stackoverflow question,) but you are *assuming* that `width` will be greater than 0, so you are *assuming* that your loop will execute at least one.  The compiler is kind enough to point out to you that it is not safe on your behalf to make such assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

You declare a variable, but don't assign anything to it:

```
Color p;
```

So it's default value is `null`.  Then you *might* assign to it, depending on runtime conditions not known at compile time:

```
for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
    p = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
```

(Hint: if `width` is less than or equal to `0` then this loop never iterates.)  Then you use the value, assuming it's been assigned:

```
a = p.A;
```

The compiler it telling you that it *might not* have been assigned a value.  Hence the message.